# Getting Div Container Height In Javascript When Div Contains Floated Content (Without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the height of a div container that has no height initially set and contains a floated element.  The `offsetHeight` property keeps coming up `0`.  I am able to get the height if I set the containing div's overflow property to `hidden`.  Is there a better method than this?

I have an example in jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6RQMb/.  It's my first time using jsFiddle for testing, so let me know if I did anything incorrectly...

In case I messed something up with jsFiddle (and because stackoverflow requested it), here's the example info:

HTML

```
<div id="container"><p>Some text that gives this element height</p></div>
```

CSS

```
p {float:left;}

/* uncomment next line and it works, without it the alert comes back with 0

#container {overflow:hidden;}

*/
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
alert( document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight );
```

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't require you to add the doctype, body and html elements. You can get right to `<div id="containerDiv">...` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `clearfix` method to force your container element to "expand" and actually wrap all its child floating elements.

```
#containerDiv:after { content:"."; clear:both; visibility:hidden; display:block; height:0; position:relative; }
```

This technique requires that the browser support CSS generated content. There are variants of this technique that can be used to support browsers as low as IE6. [Chris Coyier explains here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/2vQVJ/1/

EDIT: If you're only interested in supporting IE8+, you can use the much cleaner `.clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }` and add the `clearfix` class to the element you want self-cleared to keep that CSS to a minimum.

Comment: That's pretty interesting too, but it still uses css to solve it.  I'm so anal retentive that I was hoping for an all javascript solution, but it seems as though this quirk only gets solved from css.  Thank you so much for your time on this Rémi!

Comment: It stinks that I can't give you an upvote for your trouble (lowly 1 reputation...)

Comment: Would using a script that injects CSS to your page be a viable solution?

Comment: Yeah, the solutions are all viable (css directly or javascript injected css).  I just wanted confirmation that I was making the right decision in using css and that there wasn't something out there that I was missing.

Comment: Anyway, I whipped this up so it stays a JavaScript -- and vanilla at that! -- only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/2vQVJ/4/